# How to reference two foreign key attributes within one column?

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm working on building a database in Oracle SQL developer. In context to the scenario I have a primary table which holds two rovers.

Here is the code for that table:

```
CREATE TABLE "ROVER" (
Rover_Model_ID varchar(7) NOT NULL,
Rover_Name varchar(50),
Manufacturer varchar(50),
CONSTRAINT Rover_PK PRIMARY KEY (Rover_Model_ID)
);
```

The way I currently have it, is that there are two rovers in this table. **(Refer to the image at the end of the post)**

There is also another table called Thermal_System_Components. Which has 3 component entries that both of the rovers use.

```
CREATE TABLE "THERMAL_SYSTEM_COMPONENT" (
Component_ID INT,
Component_Type varchar(20),
Rover_Model_ID INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT TSC_PK PRIMARY KEY (Component_ID),
CONSTRAINT TSC_FK FOREIGN KEY (Rover_Model_ID) REFERENCES 
ROVER(Rover_Model_ID) 
);
```

My question relates to this scenario. There are 3 components which both rovers use, so I wondered how do I go about successfully inputting data into these tables to highlight that BOTH rovers use each of the 3 components. I've inserted the table of my initial concept down below.

If anyone could help clarify this for me I'd be most appreciative.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a [many-to-many relationship](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_(data_model)).

What you need is a third table, mapping rovers to components. Each pair of rover/component takes one row in this table, so there will be six rows total.

```
CREATE TABLE "ROVER_HAS_COMPONENT" (
Component_ID INT NOT NULL,
Rover_Model_ID INT NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT TSC_PK PRIMARY KEY (Component_ID, Rover_Model_ID),
CONSTRAINT TSC_FK FOREIGN KEY (Component_ID) REFERENCES 
THERMAL_UNIT_COMPONENT(Component_ID), 
CONSTRAINT TSC_FK FOREIGN KEY (Rover_Model_ID) REFERENCES 
ROVER(Rover_Model_ID) 
);
```

You don't need the Rover_Model_ID in your component table.

PS: You also need the data type in each foreign key column to match the data type of the primary key they reference.

Comment: So it would be like: ROV-001/01, ROV-001/02, ROV-001/03, ROV-002/01, ROV-002/02, ROV-002/03

Comment: Well, in the table I describe, the component comes first in each pair, but you've got the idea.